# How to call one script to another script in monkey talk automation tool for iOS

Tags: testing, build-automation, monkeytalk, manual-testing

Is there any Solution for: How to call one script to another script in monkey talk automation tool for iOS

Thanks,
Arihant

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two scripts scriptabc.mt and scriptxyz.mt

if you want to call scriptabc.mt from scriptxyz.mt then your scriptxyz.mt should be as below

```
Script scriptabc.mt Run
```

Please let me know if it helps.